# Circle sector find arms

Tags: math, geometry

Can someone explain how to find an end arm of a circle sector given an angle and a start arm -both arms are descibed as a vector(x,y,z) (and the other way around)? I'm trying to determine if a point belongs to a circle sector, but I don't have the arms, just a vector that is inbetween them.

Comment: It is worth to describe the problem better, define known values, perhaps show simple picture

Comment: Here is the picture https://imgur.com/a/HPNYBIG

Comment: Emm.. Do you work in 3D ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture, you have center, bisector direction ("vector") and half-angle `alpha`. To check if point lies inside sector, you don't need `arms`. Just calculate cosine of angle between "vector" and center-point and compare with cosine of `alpha`. For 2D case:

```
 lp = sqrt((px-cx)^2+(py-cy)^2)
 lv = sqrt(vx^2+vy^2)
 cost = ((px-cx)*vx + (py-cy)*vy) / (lp*lv)
 if cost >= cos(alpha) :
      inside
```